# '?'must be followed by a call, member lookup or subscript

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined a String type computed property:

```
var name : String? {
   //an optional variable
   var theName : String?

  if SOME_CONDITION {
     theName = “I have a name”
 }
 //ERROR: '?'must be followed by a call, member lookup or subscript
 return theName?
}
```

I want to return whatever `theName` is, if it is nil, return nil. So I use `return theName?` , I don’t want to have runtime error. The compiler however raise an error `'?'must be followed by a call, member lookup or subscript` Why? How to get rid of it.

Comment: You've declared `name` as a String, not an Optional String (`String?`)...

Comment: Right, I need to declare `name` as a String? as well. Please see my update, I got new error now.

Comment: Remove the `?` on the end of `theName`.

Comment: @AbakerSmith, please make a normal answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but @Michal has answered your question perfectly well and given a nice, cleaner alternative :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? Looks more elegant to me:

```
var name : String? {
    let condition = true // your own condition here of course
    return condition ? "I have a name" : nil
}
```

The problem in your code:

```
var name : String? {
    var theName : String?

    let condition = true // your own condition here of course
    if condition {
        theName = "I have a name"
    }

    return theName // get rid of the ? here
}
```

The field `theName` is already optional, no need to add another `?` there.

Why is my proposed solution **not an alternate** solution:

The construct I used is called *ternary operator*:

> The ternary conditional operator is a special operator with three parts, which takes the form question ? answer1 : answer2. It is a shortcut for evaluating one of two expressions based on whether question is true or false. If question is true, it evaluates answer1 and returns its value; otherwise, it evaluates answer2 and returns its value.

It behaves like the if statement but is suitable here as it is shorter and thus clearer to read: *Depending on the condition, the value is either `theName` or nil*. You really don't need to assign the value to any other variable, because, afterall, you are computing it, so might as well simply return it as the condition decides, what the value is.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I am not looking for an alternative way, I just want to make my code working to learn where I am wrong.

Comment: This is not alternative solution, it is THE solution - you want to return an optional value. This returns an optional value as you want it.

Comment: I also added your code but modified that it works - but really if you look at my proposed solution and your code, it is the same thing.

Comment: great! Specially for the ternary as it reduces code and of course compiler overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `?` to the end of a **type** makes it `Optional`.
Adding `?` to the end of an **optional variable** invokes [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

> You specify optional chaining by placing a question mark (?) after the
>   optional value on which you wish to call a property, method or
>   subscript if the optional is non-nil. This is very similar to placing
>   an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the
>   unwrapping of its value. The main difference is that optional chaining
>   fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping
>   triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.
>
> To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a nil
>   value, the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional
>   value, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying
>   returns a non-optional value. You can use this optional return value
>   to check whether the optional chaining call was successful (the
>   returned optional contains a value), or did not succeed due to a nil
>   value in the chain (the returned optional value is nil).
>
> Specifically, the result of an optional chaining call is of the same
>   type as the expected return value, but wrapped in an optional. A
>   property that normally returns an Int will return an Int? when
>   accessed through optional chaining.

---

#### Example

```
class Foo {
    var bar: Int
}

var x: Foo? // ? is attached to type Foo, it makes x an optional variable

let y: Int? = x?.bar // ? is attached to the variable x, this is optional chaining, it makes .bar return Int?
```